# Ćuk Converter circuit analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter

I am confused by the current path of the Ćuk converter when it is at position one where the mosfet is conducting[image: Ćuk converter]
[image: my expected circuit]
The circuit analysis results in the two circuits below. What is the current path? Why is there current passing through capacitor C1?[image: cuk analysis]

Comment: The arrows \$i_1\$ and \$i_{C1}\$ etc show the current paths... Your 3rd picture shows the simplified circuit when the mosfet is conduction. Why did you post the 4th picture? Anyway, in the 3rd picture, capacitor C1 is discharging, the current path indicated by \$i_{C1}\$

Comment: @Huisman how would C1 discharge since only I1 will be passing through the mosfet? (Please refer to my edit). 4th picture shows the circuit at position 2.

Answer (score 0):

The low side sink current switch causes a  high release voltage after clamp to 0V.

[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate. I don’t think I understand what you are trying to say. Thank you

Comment: Do you not understand flyback or back EMF or V=LdI/dt ?

Answer (score 0):

> how would C1 discharge since only I1 will be passing through the mosfet?
>   Because it had been charged when the mosfet was *not* conducting as shown in your edited question, picture 6.

In picture 2, when the mosfet is open, and C is being charged through D1. This is simplified in picture 6: the current \$i_1\$ is charging C1 and \$i_1 = i_{C1}\$.

When the mosfet is closed in picture 2, the positive terminal of C1 is grounded, so, C1 is giving a negative voltage wrt to ground. D2 is reversed biased with respect to C1, so D2 doesn't play a role and is left out/left open in the simplified circuit shown in picture 5. C1 is now discharging, with discharge current \$i_C1\$.
Current \$i_1\$ is just running circles through Vg, L1 and the closed mosfet and has nothing to do with the *discharging* of C1 in this simplified model.

Comment: In position 2, how does the current i1 go through Vg and L1 when that path is discharging the capacitor C1 through current Ic1? Do I1 and Ic1 go through the Mosfet when it’s on ( switch is at position 2)?